# Haskell creating map and foldr function for new datatype

Tags: haskell, functor, foldable

I have written a data structure,

```
data Bit a = Add a (Bit a) | End deriving (Show,Eq)
data Bits a = Bits (Bit a) (Bit a) deriving (Show,Eq)
```

but am struggling to create a map and foldr function for them.

So far I have this:

```
instance Functor Bit 
    where
       fmap _ (End) = End
       fmap f (Add x (y)) = Add (f x) $ (fmap f y)

instance Foldable Bit
    where 
       foldr _ z (End) = z 
       foldr f z (Add x (y)) = f x $ foldr f z y

instance Functor Bits 
    where 
       fmap _ (Bits (End) (End)) = Bits (End) (End)
       fmap f (Bits (Add x (y)) (End)) = error "dont know what to put here"

instance Foldable Bits
    where 
       foldr _ z (Bits (End) (End)) = z
       foldr f z (Bits (Add x (y)) (End) = Bits (f x $ f y) (End)
       foldr f z (Bits (Add x (y)) (Add a (b)) = error "dont know"
```

Any idea on how to implement them? Also not sure if I am missing anything so please let me know if that is also the case.

Comment: Remember that `Bits a` is equivalent to `[a]` where `Add = (:)` and `End = []`, and inspect the functor instance for lists.

Comment: Turn on language extensions and just derive them? :p

Comment: For `Bits` you are matching too deeply. Try `fmap f (Bits l r) = Bits (fmap f l) (fmap f r)`. See if you can come up with a foldable instance now?

Comment: For foldr i have tried `foldr _ z (Bits (End) (End)) = z ` and `foldr f z (Bits (Add x (y)) (Add l (r))) = f x $ foldr f z y $ f l $ foldr f z r ` , but i receive an error saying it couldnt match the expected type b -> b with actual type b. Not really sure how to solve this now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier to implement the `Foldable` instances via `foldMap`:

```
import Data.Monoid

data Bit a = Add a (Bit a) | End deriving (Show,Eq)
data Bits a = Bits (Bit a) (Bit a) deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Functor Bit where
  fmap _ End = End
  fmap f (Add x b) = Add (f x) $ fmap f b

instance Foldable Bit where
  foldMap _ End = mempty
  foldMap f (Add x b) = f x <> foldMap f b

instance Functor Bits where
  fmap f (Bits l r) = Bits (fmap f l) (fmap f r)

instance Foldable Bits where
  foldMap f (Bits l r) = foldMap f l <> foldMap f r
```

Here's some GHCi examples:

```
*Q51009307> foldr (\x a -> show x ++ a) "" $ End
""
*Q51009307> foldr (\x a -> show x ++ a) "" $ Add 1 $ End
"1"
*Q51009307> foldr (\x a -> show x ++ a) "" $ Add 1 $ Add 2 $ End
"12"
*Q51009307> foldr (\x a -> show x ++ a) "" $ Add 1 $ Add 2 $ Add 3 $ End
"123"
*Q51009307> foldMap Sum $ Bits (Add 1 $ End) End
Sum {getSum = 1}
*Q51009307> foldMap Sum $ Bits (Add 1 $ Add 2 $ End) (Add 1 $ End)
Sum {getSum = 4}
*Q51009307> foldr (+) 0 $ Bits (Add 1 $ Add 2 $ End) (Add 1 $ End)
4
```

Comment: Took me some time so understand the code but ill definitely use,never knew you could do it like that, thank you very much!